# System-Wide Undo Operations

Tags: windows-7, restore, undo

Many, if not all applications have undo and redo operations available, but sometimes I want to undo or redo actions I have done outside a program that has affected it.

> For instance, say I have opened the task manager and ended Google
>   Chrome because it told me it had been crashing. I find and fix the
>   problem, and attempt to restore the Chrome windows I once had open.
>   However, the essential recovery data was not stored by Chrome before I
>   ended the program.

Situations like these are normally very annoying to remedy because you have to go through Chrome's history and find every site you want to recover. They could be easily solved however by operating-system wide undos, because I could undo the end-task operation, which would restore the program's states.

Therefore,
**I'm looking for software or built in Windows functionality that would allow me to perform system-wide undos and redos.** I have 12GB of ram, so that won't be an issue either.

Comment: Interested, so I favorited :) Though I'm pretty sure such a thing doesn't exist. I don't think you can access full application images in your RAM.

Comment: @SimonVerbeke thanks, but why not up-vote as well?

Comment: The closest thing would be to run the operating system as a virtual machine. Then you can quickly save and restore snapshots. I currently do this with my XP and Windows 7 machines using VirtualBox.